# Custom Sorting (IComparer on three fields)

Tags: c#, .net, comparison

I have a person class with three fields, Title, Name, Gender and I would like to create a Custom Sort for it to sort it first by Title, then by Name and then by Gender ascending:

```
public class SortPerson : IComparer
    {
        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            (…)
        }
    }
```

I know how to do this for only one variable to compare against:
But How would I have to proceed with three?

```
public class SortPerson : IComparer
        {

int IComparer.Compare(object a, object b)
   {
      Person p1=(Person)a;
      Person p2=(Person)b;
      if (p1.Title > p2.Title)
         return 1;
      if (p1.Title < p2.Title)
         return -1;
      else
         return 0;
   }
}
```

Many Thanks,

Comment: What do you think you should do? One field should naturally be more important, correct? Then another? And finally the last? So compare the first field. If that result is 0, then compare the second. If that result is 0, compare the third. Return the result. Turn that into a method and you've got a start. Then refactor it.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
//Assuming all the fields implement IComparable
int result = a.field1.CompareTo(b.field1);
if (result == 0)
  result = a.field2.CompareTo(b.field2);
if (result == 0)
  result = a.field3.CompareTo(b.field3);
return result;
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't know what's the use you have for the comparer, but maybe you could use instead of a comparer the "order by" LINQ statement, which allows to sort by various fields:

```
var orderedListPersons =
    from p in listPersons
    orderby p.Title, p.Name, p.Gender
    select person;
```

will order listPersons the way you want. You can also use the LINQ OrderBy and ThenBy methods for the same thing with a different syntax:

```
var orderedlistPersons = listPersons.OrderBy(p => p.Title).ThenBy(p => p.Name).ThenBy(p => p.Gender);
```

Comment: IComparer is usefull to define an order on a type and then use it in linq orderby: listPersons.OrderBy(p => p)

Comment: Linq query recreates the collection and generally will take more resources - this could be negligible in some cases, but important in others. `Sort()` on the other hand will just move values (pointers) around in same collection.

Answer (score 1):

Sort on one field at a time, in order of precedence, only continuing to the next field if the previous field compare resulted in 0 (fields equal).  See the following for an example of a 2-field sort.

http://csharp.2000things.com/2010/10/30/135-implementing-icomparable-to-allow-sorting-a-custom-type/

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to implement the interface like this.

```
public class Person : IComparer<Person>
{
    public string Titel { get; set; }

    int IComparer<Person>.Compare(Person x, Person y)
    {
        if (x is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(x));
        if (y is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(y));

        return x.Titel.CompareTo(y.Titel);                      
    }
}
```

Sometimes though you might have a Little more Control ober how you'd like to sort. Sure you can use linq however then you'd have to make a list garbage allocations loss in speed and it is really not to hard to do when implementing the IComparer interface.

Have a look at the below sample and you will see that you can combine as many properties as you need.

```
public class Person : IComparable<Person>, IComparer<Person>
{
    public string Titel { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime? SomeOptionalValue { get; set; }

    int IComparer<Person>.Compare(Person x, Person y)
    {       
        return (x as IComparable).CompareTo(y);
    }

    int IComparable<Person>.CompareTo(Person other)
    {
        if (other is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(other));
        int result = this.Titel.CompareTo(other.Titel);

        //chain the other properties in the order you'd like to
        //have them sorted. 
        if (result == 0)
            result = this.FirstName.CompareTo(other.FirstName);

        if (result == 0)
            result = this.LastName.CompareTo(other.LastName);

        //use optional values as well as call the compare implementation on a class
        if (result == 0 && SomeOptionalValue.HasValue && other.SomeOptionalValue.HasValue)
            result = DateTime.Compare(this.SomeOptionalValue.Value, other.SomeOptionalValue.Value);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If repeated code gives you the ick and you're wanting code that you can write once and apply to various different classes, you can implement it in a generic extension-method way like this.

Here's my static extension methods class:

```cs
public static class SortabilityExtensions
{
    public static int CompareTo<T>(this T a, T b, params Func<T, IComparable>[] getVals) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        foreach (var getVal in getVals)
        {
            int comparison = getVal(a).CompareTo(getVal(b));
            if (comparison != 0)
                return comparison;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And then to get my `IComparable` implementation in my Person class as per the original post, with sorting by *Title* then *Name* then *Gender*, my `CompareTo` can look like this:

```cs
public int CompareTo(Person other)
{
    return this.CompareTo(other, a => a.Title, a => a.Name, a => a.Gender);
}
```