# Sorteddictionary with Color key

Tags: c#, winforms

```
SortedDictionary<Color, int> bucket = new SortedDictionary<Color, int>(new MyComparer());

        for (int col = 0; col < image.Width; col++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < image.Height; row++)
            {
                Color c = image.GetPixel(col, row);

                if (bucket.ContainsKey(c))
                    bucket[c]++;
                else
                {
                    if (c == Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 15, 12))
                        MessageBox.Show("First time " + c + " " + bucket.ContainsKey(c));
                    bucket.Add(c, 1);
                }
            }
        }
```

But the MessageBox is showed two times (for normal digital picture). Then I if want to do something like

```
SortedDictionary<Color, int> newBucket = new SortedDictionary<Color, int>(bucket, new ColorComparer(channel));
```

It ends with exception, that tells me "An item with the same key has already been added." But I checked it, in the code above and it returns `False`. Am I missing something?

btw. MyComparer

```
class MyComparer : IComparer<Color>
{
 public int Compare(Color x, Color y)
        {
                if (x == y)
                    return 0;                                  
                else if (x.R > y.R)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return -1;            
         }
}
```

Comment: In your comparer you need to compare all `Color` fields https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501501/custom-sorting-icomparer-on-three-fields

Comment: @KostyaK Oh, it is working, thanks. I thought, that colorA == colorB is enough. Well anyway... thank you very much :)

Comment: No problem. :)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the dictionary gets confused, because if the colors are not equal and `x.R == y.R` then `Compare(x, y)` returns `-1`. If later in the insertion process, the dictionary compares the same values again in the reversed order `Compare(y, x)` returns `-1` again, but to be consistent with the previous result it should return `+1`. So the dictionary becomes corrupted.

In other words: if `a > b` then `b < a` must be true as well. Or with the comparer: `Compare(a, b) == -Compare(b, a)` must be true!

The only way to make the comparer consistent, is to compare all the color channels (even if you are only interested in the red color for the order. E.g.:

```
class MyComparer : IComparer<Color>
{
    public int Compare(Color x, Color y)
    {
        if (x.R > y.R) return +1;
        if (x.R < y.R) return -1;
        return x.ToArgb().CompareTo(y.ToArgb());
    }
}
```

Another possibility is to only store the red component in a `SortedDictionary<byte, int>`.

Comment: KostyaK's solution works for me but you give me a good information, so thanks :)